# Segmentation fault while searching data in a txt file (C)

Tags: c, file, text, struct, segmentation-fault

I have the following functions:

```
void find(void) {
  nd = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node) * 14);

  FILE *openedfile;

  openedfile = fopen("NSFNet.txt", "r");

  if (openedfile == NULL) {
    printf("Error, file no existente");   
    exit(1);
  } 

  fseek(openedfile, 175, SEEK_SET);
  char linea[300];
  char *aux;
  fgets(linea, 300, openedfile); 
  char *checker ="0";
  int counter = 0;
  int i = 0;

  while (fgets(linea, 300,openedfile) != NULL) {
    aux = strtok(linea, "[]"); 

    int value = atoi(aux);
    if (value == i) {
      counter++;
    }
    if (value != i) {
      nd[i].links = counter;
      printf("El contador es:\n");
      printf("%d\n", i);
      printf("%d\n", nd[i].links);
      counter = 1;
      i++;    
    }
  }
}
```

**And the next one:**

```
void test(void) {
  nd = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node) * 14);

  FILE *openedfile;
  openedfile = fopen("NSFNet.txt", "r");

  if (openedfile == NULL) {
    printf("Error, file no existente");   
    exit(1);
  } 

  fseek(openedfile, 175, SEEK_SET);

  char linea[300];
  char *aux;
  fgets(linea, 300, openedfile); 
  char *checker ="0";
  int counter = 0;
  int i = 0;

  while (fgets(linea, 300,openedfile) != NULL) {
    aux = strtok(linea, "]"); 
    aux = strtok(NULL, "]");
    aux = strtok(NULL, "\t");

    printf("%s \n",aux);
  }
}
```

This codes extracts some data from the following txt file:

```
Number of nodes: 14
Number of links: 42
==================================================
source  dest.   hops    path (link ids)
==================================================
[0] [1] 1   0
[0] [2] 1   2
[0] [3] 2   0-8
[0] [4] 3   0-8-12
[0] [5] 2   2-10
[0] [6] 4   0-8-12-18
[0] [7] 1   4
[0] [8] 2   4-26
[0] [9] 3   4-26-28
[0] [10]    3   0-8-14
```

The first code extracts the numbers of the first column, and the second code extracts the numbers of the third column. Both functions work fine separately but I want to create a condition. I mixed both functions into one function:

```
void find2(void) {
  nd = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node) * 14);

  FILE *openedfile;

  openedfile = fopen("NSFNet.txt", "r");

  if (openedfile == NULL) {
    printf("Error, file no existente");   
    exit(1);
  } 

  fseek(openedfile, 175, SEEK_SET);

  char linea[300];
  char *aux;
  char *aux2;
  fgets(linea, 300, openedfile); 
  char *checker ="0";
  int counter = 0;
  int i = 0;

  while (fgets(linea, 300,openedfile) != NULL) {
    aux2 = strtok(linea, "]"); 

    aux2 = strtok(NULL, "]");
    aux2 = strtok(NULL, "\t");

    int value = atoi(aux);
    int hops = atoi(aux2);

    if (value == i && hops == 1) {
      counter++;
    }
    if (value != i) {
      nd[i].links = counter;
      printf("El contador es:\n");
      printf("%d\n", i);
      printf("%d\n", nd[i].links);
      counter = 1;
      i++;    
    }
  }
}
```

The mixed function has the following error: `exited, segmentation fault.`
Please, can someone help me find my error.

Comment: You are not checking whether `aux` is NULL after calling `strtok` and before passing it to `atoi` or `printf`, which seems a little over-confident.

Comment: You should also check that `i < 14` before attempting to use it as an index.

Comment: `int value=atoi(aux);` however, `aux` is never initialized. This causes your segment violation and abort.

Comment: Step through your code in a debugger and watch it execute.  Second,when parsing text files performing a seek based on number of characters is bad practice.  i.e. don't do this: `fseek(openedfile,175, SEEK_SET);`  It would be better read 5 lines and skip them.  Your assumption that the header will always be the same number of bytes will probably break at some point in time.

Answer (score 0):

It was a null value. I was transforming a string (null) into a integer, and that is why the error ocurred.

Thanks everyone!